# How to Integrate my React app bot in any website using script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, bots

I have made a bot in React.js and made a JavaScript file using WebPack like this:

`<script src="https://my-example-js-file.netlify.app/bot.js" defer></script>`

Now I am placing this script tag in  tag of my another React.js application.

But when I run the application, I see my bot icon in bottom right corner of my application for a split second, and then it disappears. Why is it not working and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you placing the script in your `index.html` or directly in your React component?

Maybe try this method of loading in a script in React:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://my-example-js-file.netlify.app/bot.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);
```